# Getting a FTP File's MD5 Checksum in Java

Tags: java, ftp, md5

How do I get MD5 checksum for File direct on reading FTP files(without downloading) in JAVA ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that. To compute **MD5** hash you need to access every single byte on the file. Hence, you need to download it first. In Java or in any other programming language for that matter.